# Relation does not exist, in PostgreSQL, Django

Tags: django, postgresql, pgadmin

So I've created a new model in Django, then executed both python `manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` in the right order. But then for some reason I accidentally dropped the table(relation) in PgAdmin (I know it sounds silly). So I tried deleting all the files in migrations folder but the **init**.py file. Then I ran the two commands above again, but could see no table in the PgAdmin. 
 What should I do, aside from creating a table myself in PgAdmin? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It won't work, because entry for all the migrations are already stored inside a table named `django_migrations`. So even if you run `makemigrations` after deleting all the migration files, it won't create a new one. So here is three ways you can fix it.

### One: Drop DB(if data is not important)

Drop database and create a new one. Run `makemigrations` and `migrate` command.

### Two: Create that table manually

If you already deleted all the migration files, you better restore them. You can use git for this: `git checkout /path/to/migration/folder`. Then you can manually create the table.

### Three: Delete entries from `django_migrations`

*I assumed you have deleted all the migration files. So this part covers the whole project. But @DenizKaplan has explained better way to do this.*

If you are not using git, or no way to restore these files, then you can follow these steps:

1. Backup your database
2. Delete all entries from `djang_migrations` table
3. Run `./manage.py makemigrations` to generate migration file
4. Run `./manage.py migrate <your lost app>` to migrate your app(which you have lost in DB).
5. Run `./manage.py migrate --fake` to fake the rest of apps.

Comment: Thanks! if I delete all entries from ```django_migrations```, will all of my models be deleted as well?

Comment: I've just cleared all problems with option one. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

There are some steps you need to check. If you have an empty output after `makemigrations` operations, you may need to check for `django_migrations` table to remove rows related to apps that you have working with. If this won't help at first place, you need check INSTALLED_APPS, maybe you may accidently delete apps. If all these not work, please give some detailed information about the error.

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to delete the record in ```django_migrations``` regarding the app, but I have no idea on how to do it. How do I delete that specific row?

Comment: You can run raw sql statement to delete spesifc rows with and IDE or in python shell, you can create a new connection to commit that sql command. The sql may be like `delete from django_migrations where app='your_app_name';` Then you are free to run `makemigrations` and `migrate` again.